# C# - Resize Image after upload

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio

I'm trying to resize the image after upload but it doesn't work

What's wrong?

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog(); 

     open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp"; 
       if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var imagem = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
        var resizedImage = new Bitmap(imagem, pictureBox1.Size);
       pictureBox1.Image = resizedImage;
        } 

 }
```

Comment: You tell us: what happens?

Comment: PictureBox already has the ability to resize an image like this, Set the [BackgroundImageLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout.aspx) property to [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.imagelayout.aspx). It will make the image the same size as the PictureBox

Comment: why down vote? I have said what happens...The image appears not full in picture box...appears cropped

Comment: Re-read your question, your comment is the first time you told us.

Comment: I have said that I'm trying resize the image but doesnt work..if I'm trying resize an image and it doesn't work...theeem the image was not resized...It's obvious

Comment: @musefan answer the question and I mark as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PictureBox already has the ability to resize an image.

If you are assigning the image using the `Image` property then you can set the [SizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx) property to [StretchImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx). Which means you code would look like this:

```
var imagem = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
pictureBox1.Image = imagem;
```

If you want to assign the image using the `BackgroundImage` property then you can set the [BackgroundImageLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout.aspx) property to [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.imagelayout.aspx). Which means you code would look like this:

```
var imagem = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = imagem;
```

---

From personal experience I have found the PictureBox control to be a pain. If you are needing to change or remove the image at any point I always found I needed to explicitly dispose of the image or it gave me memory leaks, and in some cases just plain errors. It is worth noting that when you need to do custom drawing or rendering in WinForms then the `Panel` control is a much better option. You can draw images onto a `Panel` too, but depending on your needs, you may be find just using the `PictureBox`

Comment: I think you have the wrong property, he needs [SizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [SizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx) of your picture box

from the MSDN

> By default, in Normal mode, the Image is positioned in the upper-left corner of the PictureBox, and any part of the image that is too big for the PictureBox is clipped. Using the StretchImage value causes the image to stretch or shrink to fit the PictureBox. Using the Zoom value causes the image to be stretched or shrunk to fit the PictureBox; however, the aspect ratio in the original is maintained.

So change the setting on `PictureBox1` from `Normal` to `StretchImage` or `Zoom` depending on which affect you want. It will make it act how you want and you can remove your resize code.

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't need this code, just set the SizeMode Property to StretchImage.
However the extremely irritating reason your code doesn't work, is changing from one image to another does not in and of itself trigger the picture box to redraw.

The two usual solutions are to either

Call `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` after you assign the image, or do `pictureBox1.Image = null`, before you assign it.

You might have to do one of these even with SizeMode set, if the image is the same size as the PictureBox, can't remember.